# How to modify a few items in a levelDB database, and replicate the modifications on a remote with a minimal number of bytes?

Tags: python, database, leveldb

I have a levelDB database created with:

```
import plyvel, os
db = plyvel.DB('testdb', create_if_missing=True)
for i in range(100_000):
    db.put(str(i).encode(), os.urandom(100))
```

The `testdb/` directory is synchronized with a distant version.

Now I modify a few items:

```
db = plyvel.DB('testdb')
db.put(b'2786', os.urandom(100))
db.delete(b'124')
```

I'd like to replicate the modifications on the remote, but with the least number of bytes.

I don't have SSH command access on remote, so I can't run Python there, I can't run a leveldb specific binary. I only have SFTP commands (open file, seek, write, close, delete files, etc.).

**How to replicate the modifications on a remote with a minimal number of bytes?**

Among these files:

```
000008.log
CURRENT
LOG
MANIFEST-000002
```

can some of them be useful to know the diff between the previous state, in order to replicate it on remote?

Comment: you want to modiy remote leveldb files with sftp commands to make them match local files?

Comment: @ren exactly this!

Comment: This is crazy:D For example, you can't modify a file using sftp commands, just delete it and write new one.  Your best bet is to somehow make a replica of a snapshot of db and upload it entirely to ftp

Comment: Besides playing with internal leveldb files will almost certainly corrupt it

Comment: Or have a look at rsync

Comment: @ren *"For example, you can't modify a file using sftp commands, just delete it and write new one."* No no, this is wrong (I used to think the same too!). You *can* open a file, move at a byte-position 2736, write 300 bytes, move ("seek") elsewhere, write there. You can also open a file in "append" `a+` mode with SFTP :)

Comment: Well maybe, not sure, but your source file still has to be unused by leveldb, so you need ofline local copy.

Comment: And then use rsync :)

Comment: @ren I'm coding a rsync-like new tool ;) so I won't reuse rsync.

Comment: :D Ok, it's always more fun to write your own tool, can't blame you